# memory leak with size of arraylist 

Tags: java, android

I have this in one activity :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

time=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.time);
...
public void mass_func(){
           ...
       double ttime=Double.parseDouble(time.getText().toString().trim());
       double res=mass*(Math.pow(0.5,ttime/half_time));
       ....
       //filling the array
       int temp=(int) ttime;

       ArrayList <MyDouble> final_mass=new ArrayList <MyDouble>(temp);//i want the size to be maximum as the ttime

           for (int i=0;i<=temp;i++){
          MyDouble m1=new MyDouble(mass*(Math.pow(0.5,i/half_time)));
          final_mass.add(m1);           
                        }

      Intent i=new Intent(this,mass_calcs.class);
        ...
       i.putExtra("time",ttime);
       i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("final_mass",final_mass);
       startActivity(i);  

     }
```

From the  mass_calcs activity i just pass the values to the LineGraph activity.
The LineGraph activity is:

```
public class LineGraph_mass extends Activity {

    ...
    private Double ttime;
    //ArrayList <MyDouble> final_mass=new ArrayList <MyDouble>(ttime.intValue());
    ArrayList <MyDouble> final_mass=new ArrayList <MyDouble>( 10000);
```

The problem is that when the user inputs a value for time about '4000' the application crashes.
I am getting error "GC_FOR_MALLOC freed..." which implies memory leakage.

From the reading i have done ,i saw one way to deal is giving the arraylist a size.

But how could i do that in my situation?

I am defining "ArrayList  final_mass=new ArrayList (temp);" at the first activity and  tried sth like "...==new ArrayList (ttime.intValue());" at the LineGraph ,but it won't work.

(I also tried sth like "...==new ArrayList (10000)" but it doesn't work either.

--------------UPDATE-----------------------------

Here is the log.txt

```
       ....
         I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com....Radiation/.mass_calcs (has extras) }
         E/JavaBinder(59): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
         W/ActivityManager(59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
         W/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{4403c310 com...Radiation/.mass_calcs}
        W/WindowManager(59): Key dispatching timed out sending to <null>: no window ready for key dispatch
        W/WindowManager(59): Previous dispatch state: {{KeyEvent{action=1 code=10 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=4 mFlags=8} to Window{..Radiation/com.w..o.Radiation.number_mass paused=false} @ 1329130580604 lw=Window{440288e8 com....Radiation/com....Radiation.number_mass paused=false} lb=android.os.BinderProxy@43ff0990 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=true fp=false mcf=Window{440288e8 com....Radiation/com...adiation.number_mass paused=false}}}
        W/WindowManager(59): Current dispatch state: {{KeyEvent{action=0 code=4 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=158 mFlags=8} to null @ 1329130602027 lw=null lb=null fin=true gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=null}}
         I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 277 SIG: 3
        I/dalvikvm(277): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
         I/dalvikvm(277): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
        I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 59 SIG: 3
        I/dalvikvm(59): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
         I/dalvikvm(59): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
         I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 118 SIG: 3
        I/dalvikvm(118): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
         I/dalvikvm(118): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
        I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 260 SIG: 3
         I/dalvikvm(260): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
        I/dalvikvm(260): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
         I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 197 SIG: 3
         I/dalvikvm(197): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
         I/dalvikvm(197): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
        I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 244 SIG: 3
         I/dalvikvm(244): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
        ...
       I/dalvikvm(251): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
         I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 127 SIG: 3
      I/dalvikvm(127): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
         I/dalvikvm(127): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
        I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 223 SIG: 3
         I/dalvikvm(223): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
         I/dalvikvm(223): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
        I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 208 SIG: 3
         I/dalvikvm(208): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
         I/dalvikvm(208): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
         I/P....
         E/ActivityManager(59): ANR in com....Radiation (com....Radiation/.mass_calcs)
        E/ActivityManager(59): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
         E/ActivityManager(59): Load: 2.15 / 1.13 / 0.43
         E/ActivityManager(59): CPU usage from 17754ms to 45ms ago:
         E/ActivityManager(59):   system_server: 4% = 2% user + 1% kernel / faults: 887 minor 13 major
         E/ActivityManager(59):   evgeo.Radiation: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 190 minor 6 major
        E/ActivityManager(59):   m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 300 minor
        E/ActivityManager(59):   ndroid.settings: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 355 minor
        E/ActivityManager(59):   d.process.acore: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 188 minor
       E/ActivityManager(59):   d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 157 minor
...
        E/ActivityManager(59):   roid.alarmclock: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 174 minor
         E/ActivityManager(59):   id.defcontainer: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 156 minor
         E/ActivityManager(59):   android.protips: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 156 minor
        E/ActivityManager(59):   m.android.music: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 155 minor
        ...
        E/ActivityManager(59): TOTAL: 7% = 4% user + 3% kernel
         D/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5076 objects / 300544 bytes in 186ms
        02-13 12:56:42.976: W/WindowManager(59): No focus window, dropping: KeyEvent{action=0 code=4 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=158 mFlags=8}
        02-13 12:56:43.147: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 443 objects / 21488 bytes in 157ms
        02-13 12:56:43.147: I/dalvikvm-heap(59): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.071MB for 81076-byte allocation
        02-13 12:56:43.306: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 144 objects / 7200 bytes in 158ms
        02-13 12:56:43.446: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 298 objects / 99376 bytes in 138ms
        02-13 12:56:43.446: I/dalvikvm-heap(59): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.163MB for 162136-byte allocation
        02-13 12:56:43.586: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 103 objects / 4600 bytes in 143ms
        02-13 12:56:43.917: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 118 objects / 228512 bytes in 304ms
        02-13 12:56:44.307: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 45 objects / 167704 bytes in 348ms
        02-13 12:56:45.257: I/ARMAssembler(59): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x2429d8:0x242a94] in 20482216 ns
        02-13 12:56:46.666: W/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com..Radiation/.mass_calcs
        02-13 12:56:46.676: I/ActivityManager(59): Killing com..Radiation (pid=277): user's request
        02-13 12:56:46.676: I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 277 SIG: 9
        02-13 12:56:46.729: I/ActivityManager(59): Process com....Radiation (pid 277) has died.
        02-13 12:56:46.766: I/WindowManager(59): WIN DEATH: Window{4
        02-13 12:56:46.766: I/WindowManager(59): WIN DEATH: Window{4com....Radiation for activity com...o.Radiation/.Radiation: pid=284 uid=10043 gids={3003}
        02-13 12:56:47.406: W/InputManagerService(59): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 277 uid 10043
        02-13 12:56:47.987: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com....Radiation/.Radiation: 1237 ms (total 22978 ms)
        02-13 12:57:02.616: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=c...Radiation/.number_mass }
        02-13 12:57:03.076: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com....Radiation/.number_mass: 451 ms (total 451 ms)
        02-13 12:57:03.786: W/KeyCharacterMap(284): No keyboard for id 0
        02-13 12:57:03.786: W/KeyCharacterMap(284): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
        02-13 12:57:09.786: D/dalvikvm(284): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1788 objects / 107184 bytes in 105ms
        02-13 12:57:10.346: D/dalvikvm(284): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5790 objects / 531000 bytes in 98ms
        02-13 12:57:10.897: D/dalvikvm(284): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5888 objects / 518296 bytes in 99ms
        02-13 12:57:11.376: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com..Radiation/.mass_calcs (has extras) }
        02-13 12:57:11.486: E/JavaBinder(59): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
        02-13 12:57:21.396: W/ActivityManager(59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
        02-13 12:57:21.491: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{43fe82b0 com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation/.mass_calcs}
        02-13 13:00:05.503: W/WindowManager(59): Key dispatching timed out sending to <null>: no window ready for key dispatch
        02-13 13:00:05.503: W/WindowManager(59): Previous dispatch state: {{KeyEvent{action=1 code=10 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=4 mFlags=8} to Window{4...lb=android.os.BinderProxy@43eb9200 fin=false gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=Window{4403c720 ...
        02-13 13:00:05.506: W/WindowManager(59): Current dispatch state: {{KeyEvent{action=0 code=4 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=158 mFlags=8} to null @ 1329130805506 lw=null lb=null fin=true gfw=true ed=true tts=0 wf=false fp=false mcf=null}}
        02-13 13:00:05.506: I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 284 SIG: 3
        02-13 13:00:05.506: I/dalvikvm(284): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
        02-13 13:00:05.526: I/dalvikvm(284): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
        02-13 13:00:05.526: I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 59 SIG: 3
        02-13 13:00:05.526: I/dalvikvm(59): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
        02-13 13:00:05.596: I/dalvikvm(59): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
        ...
        02....
        02-13 13:00:05.827: I/dalvikvm(133): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
        02-13 13:00:05.897: E/ActivityManager(59): ANR in com....Radiation (com.....Radiation/.mass_calcs)
        02-13 13:00:05.897: E/ActivityManager(59): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
        02-13 13:00:05.897: E/ActivityManager(59): Load: 0.08 / 0.59 / 0.35
        02-13 13:00:05.897: E/ActivityManager(59): CPU usage from 203216ms to 49ms ago:
        02-13 13:00:05.897: E/ActivityManager(59):   system_server: 3% = 2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3251 minor 18 major
        02-13 13:00:05.897: E/ActivityManager(59):   m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 78 minor
        02-13 13:00:05.897: E/ActivityManager(59):   ronsoft.openwnn: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 169 minor 1 major
        02-13 13:00:05.897: E/ActivityManager(59):   zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 174 minor 1 major
        02-13 13:00:05.897: E/ActivityManager(59):   adbd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
        02-13 13:00:05.897: E/ActivityManager(59):   servicemanager: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
        02-13 13:00:05.897: E/ActivityManager(59):   ndroid.launcher: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 40 minor
      ...0% kernel / faults: 36 minor
        02-13 13:00:05.897: E/ActivityManager(59):   .quicksearchbox: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel ...
kernel / faults: 36 minor
        02-13 13:00:05.897: E/ActivityManager(59):  +evgeo.Radiation: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
        02-13 13:00:05.897: E/ActivityManager(59):  -evgeo.Radiation: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
        02-13 13:00:05.897: E/ActivityManager(59): TOTAL: 5% = 4% user + 1% kernel + 0% iowait + 0% softirq
        02-13 13:00:05.917: W/WindowManager(59): No focus window, dropping: KeyEvent{action=0 code=4 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=158 mFlags=8}
        02-13 13:00:06.087: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2754 objects / 465896 bytes in 161ms
        02-13 13:00:06.246: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 246 objects / 92832 bytes in 140ms
        02-13 13:00:06.406: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 104 objects / 228008 bytes in 141ms
        02-13 13:00:06.566: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 24 objects / 166848 bytes in 138ms
        02-13 13:00:09.887: W/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com....Radiation/.mass_calcs
        02-13 13:00:09.899: I/ActivityManager(59): Killing com...eo.Radiation (pid=284): user's request
        02-13 13:00:09.899: I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 284 SIG: 9
        02-13 13:00:09.937: I/ActivityManager(59): Process com.w..eo.Radiation (pid 284) has died.
        02-13 13:00:09.967: I/WindowManager(59): WIN DEATH: Window{43e98028 com....Radiation/com...Radiation.Radiation paused=false}
        02-13 13:00:09.967: I/WindowManager(59): WIN DEATH: Window{4403c720 com....Radiation/com...Radiation.number_mass paused=false}
        02-13 13:00:09.977: I/ActivityManager(59): Start proc com...adiation for activity com....Radiation/.Radiation: pid=291 uid=10043 gids={3003}
        02-13 13:00:10.556: W/InputManagerService(59): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 284 uid 10043
        02-13 13:00:11.126: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com...o.Radiation/.Radiation: 1171 ms (total 179719 ms)
        02-13 13:00:35.116: D/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
        02-13 13:00:55.099: D/dalvikvm(59): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
        02-13 13:02:48.456: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com...o.Radiation/.read }
        02-13 13:02:51.392: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.w...Radiation/.read: 2723 ms (total 2723 ms)
        02-13 13:03:29.026: D/AndroidRuntime(305): > AndroidRuntime START 
        02-13 13:03:29.026: D/AndroidRuntime(305): CheckJNI is ON
        02-13 13:03:29.236: D/AndroidRuntime(305): --- registering native functions ---
        02-13 13:03:30.366: D/dalvikvm(185): GC_EXPLICIT freed 363 objects / 22088 bytes in 96ms
        02-13 13:03:30.867: D/PackageParser(59): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl68554.tmp
        02-13 13:03:31.246: I/PackageManager(59): Removing non-system package:com...o.Radiation
        02-13 13:03:31.246: I/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com...Radiation uid=10043
        02-13 13:03:31.266: I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 291 SIG: 9
        02-13 13:03:31.277: I/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity HistoryRecord{43fb3a00 com.w..adiation/.Radiation}
        02-13 13:03:31.306: I/UsageStats(59): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.w...Radiation
        02-13 13:03:31.317: I/WindowManager(59): WIN DEATH: Window{43fcc188 com....Radiation/com..o.Radiation.Radiation paused=true}
        02-13 13:03:31.317: I/WindowManager(59): WIN DEATH: Window{43ff4430 com....Radiation/com....Radiation.read paused=false}
        02-13 13:03:31.356: W/InputManagerService(59): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 291 uid 10043
        02-13 13:03:31.737: D/PackageManager(59): Scanning package com...Radiation
        02-13 13:03:31.747: I/PackageManager(59): Package com...o.Radiation codePath changed from /data/app/com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation-2.apk to /data/app/com.w..o.Radiation-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
        02-13 13:03:31.747: I/PackageManager(59): /data/app/com....Radiation-1.apk changed; unpacking
        02-13 13:03:31.757: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com...o.Radiation-1.apk' ---
        02-13 13:03:32.406: D/dalvikvm(314): DexOpt: load 83ms, verify 367ms, opt 14ms
        02-13 13:03:32.416: D/installd(35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com....Radiation-1.apk' (success) ---
        02-13 13:03:32.426: W/PackageManager(59): Code path for pkg : com....Radiation changing from /data/app/com....Radiation-2.apk to /data/app/com...Radiation-1.apk
        02-13 13:03:32.426: W/PackageManager(59): Resource path for pkg : com....Radiation changing from /data/app/com....adiation-2.apk to /data/app/com....Radiation-1.apk
        02-13 13:03:32.426: D/PackageManager(59):   Activities:. .Radiation.Radiation .core_calcs c.Radiation.mass_calcs com....Radiation.number_cores com..Radiation.number_mass com....Radiation.help com...Radiation.help_mass com...Radiation.read org...com...Radiation.LineGraph com....Radiation.LineGraph_mass
        02-13 13:03:32.587: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5700 objects / 677864 bytes in 154ms
        02-13 13:03:32.607: I/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package comon uid=10043
        02-13 13:03:32.797: I/installd(35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com
        02-13 13:03:32.797: D/PackageManager(59): New package installed in /data/app/com.
        02-13 13:03:33.016: I/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation uid=10043
        02-13 13:03:33.126: D/dalvikvm(129): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1143 objects / 62248 bytes in 102ms
        02-13 13:03:33.336: D/dalvikvm(162): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2035 objects / 103800 bytes in 160ms
        02-13 13:03:33.517: W/RecognitionManagerService(59): no available voice recognition services found
        02-13 13:03:33.956: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5880 objects / 365616 bytes in 259ms
        02-13 13:03:34.006: I/installd(35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation-2.apk@classes.dex
        02-13 13:03:34.026: D/AndroidRuntime(305): Shutting down VM
        02-13 13:03:34.036: D/dalvikvm(305): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
        02-13 13:03:34.066: I/AndroidRuntime(305): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
        D/AndroidRuntime(320):  AndroidRuntime START 
        D/AndroidRuntime(320): CheckJNI is ON
       D/AndroidRuntime(320): --- registering native functions ---
         I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation/.Radiation }
        02-13 13:03:35.986: D/AndroidRuntime(320): Shutting down VM
        02-13 13:03:36.006: D/dalvikvm(320): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
        02-13 13:03:36.087: I/AndroidRuntime(320): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
        02-13 13:03:36.087: I/ActivityManager(59): Start proc com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation for activity com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation/.Radiation: pid=327 uid=10043 gids={3003}
        02-13 13:03:38.047: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation/.Radiation: 2072 ms (total 2072 ms)
        02-13 13:03:39.266: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation/.number_mass }
        02-13 13:03:39.847: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation/.number_mass: 557 ms (total 557 ms)
        02-13 13:03:40.196: W/KeyCharacterMap(327): No keyboard for id 0
        02-13 13:03:40.196: W/KeyCharacterMap(327): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
        02-13 13:03:44.956: D/dalvikvm(129): GC_EXPLICIT freed 868 objects / 50432 bytes in 106ms
        02-13 13:03:46.026: D/dalvikvm(327): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2384 objects / 179232 bytes in 97ms
        02-13 13:03:46.567: D/dalvikvm(327): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6370 objects / 552192 bytes in 94ms
        02-13 13:03:47.436: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation/.mass_calcs (has extras) }
        02-13 13:03:47.517: E/JavaBinder(59): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
        02-13 13:03:57.451: W/ActivityManager(59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
        02-13 13:03:57.523: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{43ff11a0 com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation/.mass_calcs}
        02-13 13:04:05.156: D/dalvikvm(185): GC_EXPLICIT freed 214 objects / 14840 bytes in 98ms
        02-13 13:04:10.167: D/dalvikvm(260): GC_EXPLICIT freed 764 objects / 55248 bytes in 96ms
        02-13 13:04:24.727: W/WindowManager(59): Key dispatching timed out sending to <null>: no window ready for key dispatch
        02-13 13:04:24.727: W/WindowManager(59): Previous dispatch state: {{KeyEvent{...
        02-13 13:04:24.727: W/WindowManager(59): Current dispatch state: {{KeyEvent{act..
       ......
        02-13 13:04:24.887: I/dalvikvm(129): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
        02-13 13:04:24.916: I/dalvikvm(129): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
        02-13 13:04:24.916: I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 260 SIG: 3
        02-13 13:04:24.916: I/dalvikvm(260): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
        02-13 13:04:24.936: I/dalvikvm(260): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
          ......
        02-13 13:04:24.976: I/dalvikvm(197): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
        02-13 13:04:24.996: I/dalvikvm(197): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
        02-13 13:04:24.996: I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 244 SIG: 3
        02-13 13:04:25.007: I/dalvikvm(244): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
        02-13 13:04:25.026: I/dalvikvm(244): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
        02-13 13:04:25.036: I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 233 SIG: 3
        02-13 13:04:25.036: I/dalvikvm(233): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
        02-13 13:04:25.056: I/dalvikvm(233): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
        02-13 13:04:25.056: I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 251 SIG: 3
        02-13 13:04:25.066: I/dalvikvm(251): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
        02-13 13:04:25.086: I/dalvikvm(251): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
        02-13 13:04:25.086: I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 127 SIG: 3
        02-13 13:04:25.096: I/dalvikvm(127): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
         ....

        02-13 13:04:25.236: I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 162 SIG: 3
        02-13 13:04:25.236: I/dalvikvm(162): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
        02-13 13:04:25.266: I/dalvikvm(162): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
         ....
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59): ANR in com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation (com.w...mass_calcs)
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59): Load: 0.34 / 0.5 / 0.36
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59): CPU usage from 259522ms to 57ms ago:
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):   system_server: 3% = 3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4845 minor 78 major
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):   adbd: 1% = 0% user + 1% kernel / faults: 119 minor
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):   d.process.acore: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2243 minor 77 major
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):   id.defcontainer: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 968 minor 2 major
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):   ndroid.launcher: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1341 minor 8 major
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):   m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 489 minor
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):   ronsoft.openwnn: 0% = 0% user + 0% kerne...
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):   rild: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 39 minor
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):   ndroid.settings: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 466 minor
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):   android.protips: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 394 minor
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):   m.android.music: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 395 minor
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):   d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 398 minor
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):   .quicksearchbox: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 407 minor
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):   zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 108 minor
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):   qemud: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / f...kernel / faults: 36 minor
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):  +evgeo.Radiation: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):  +sh: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):  +logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59):  +evgeo.Radiation: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
        02-13 13:04:25.367: E/ActivityManager(59): TOTAL: 10% = 6% user + 3% kernel + 0% iowait + 0% irq + 0% softirq
        02-13 13:04:25.396: W/WindowManager(59): No focus window, dropping: KeyEvent{action=0 code=4 repeat=0 meta=0 scancode=158 mFlags=8}
        D/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3845 objects / 289456 bytes in 143ms
         D/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 271 objects / 240072 bytes in 140ms
         D/dalvikvm(59): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 220 objects / 180856 bytes in 133ms
       W/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation/.mass_calcs
         I/ActivityManager(59): Killing com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation (pid=327): user's request
         I/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 327 SIG: 9
        I/ActivityManager(59): Process com.wordpress.androiddevgeo.Radiation (pid 327) has died.
       I/WindowManager(59): WIN DEATH: Window{43fc95b8 com.w...Radiation/com.w...Radiation.Radiation paused=false}
         I/WindowManager(59): WIN DEATH: Window{43fd5a38 com.w...Radiation/com.w..Radiation.number_mass paused=false}
         I/ActivityManager(59): Start proc com.w...Radiation for activity com....Radiation/.Radiation: pid=337 uid=10043 gids={3003}
       D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 283 objects / 10816 bytes in 275ms
        D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 47 objects / 2016 bytes in 171ms
         D/dalvikvm(33): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2 objects / 64 bytes in 141ms
        W/InputManagerService(59): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 327 uid 10043
         I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.w..o.Radiation/.Radiation: 1409 ms (total 41279 ms)
```

Comment: Would you mind logging the value of ttime : (Log.d( "value of time is " + ttime ); . Also, consider using Math.round to transform a double into an int. Casting seems rather unsafe to me.

Comment: @Snicolas:I used Math.round() but still the same.The value of ttime is whatever the user inputs.(i am not familiar with Log.d...)

Comment: What does adb logcat show ? Your error is not clear at all.

Comment: I wrote above "GC_FOR_MALLOC freed..."

Comment: this is not an error, it means memory has been garbage collected. Upper in the logcat trace you should have a more detailed error if something really wrong happens

Comment: The thing is that the app crashes.I have no errors

Comment: I maintain my point and it seems to be the point of view of @Michell Bak too. Find your real error in the stack trace of adb and report it here. We can't understand what's really going wrong. Another possibility would be that you cath an exception somewhere and do nothing in the cath statement, at least you should always log errors.

Comment: @Snicolas:I tried to use memory analyzer.I posted some results.

Comment: you better post your logcat trace.

Comment: @Snicolas:It's huge..I put some of them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't set the size of an `ArrayList` - that's basically one of the beauties of using an `ArrayList`. It's dynamic. Don't confuse it with a regular Java array, where you can define a certain size.

Comment: :Ok, how i will deal with my problem then?

Comment: I don't know what your problem is. The title reads 'How to initialize ArrayList to be as user input" - it is possible to do so (and you've already done that in your code), but I don't really see a purpose of doing so. The biggest advantage of an ArrayList is that it's capable of being dynamic - in my opinion, anyway... Regardless - it seems a bit crazy to have 10,000 items in an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

First off I would advise against make a 10,000 entry ArrayList- that cannot be necessary.

I am not 100% familiar with the problem, but if you only have so many data points, and the user enters something far off, then why not limit what the user can enter? If it is not a valid entry, tell them that in a Toast message, and censor the input so the activity doesnt crash.

And what value does ttime have in your LineGraph_mass activity?

Comment: :The ttime may have 'any' value.I can't limit the user entry.